# Preview text in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm working on a application project as my bachelor thesis and I wonder if it's possible to set a text in a Edittext box?

I'm not talking about the editText.setHint("My text"), or android:hint in the XML. I want to fetch a variable from a Web Service (This variable may change depend on what you do ).

For example. You have a shoppinglist. The list says "Go buy two pieces of bread ", and the editText Box is supposed to have " 2 " in the box (so you can directly proceed from there) but if you didn't buy two pieces of bread, you can edit it to " 1 ".

It's hard to explain this, but I hope you guys understands. If not, let me know and I'll try to explain again.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple:

```
           EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id);
            editText.setText("1", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Comment: The things is that I I want "1" to be replaced by i.e MyClass.name, but I get NullPointerException, and it doesn't work with " editText.setText("1", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE) " either.  :/

Comment: I don't get NullPointer anymore, but this is unfortunatley not what I was looking for. I want the text in the box to be "set" as in confirmed. If I press on any button it will proceed with the value that was in the box.

Comment: so , to help You and exactly understand, please post some of Your relevant code

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem now. Your solution works :). I used the wrong id to editText, that caused NullPointer. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);
            editText.setText("1");
```

Comment: I needed the "TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE" too as Opiatefuchs mentioned. It works now. Thanks for your help :)